# Overlay div on top of JavaScript element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to overlay a div(1) with a background image over the top of another div(2) which contains JavaScript (in this case Google maps API v3). Is this possible?

I've tried messing with z-index no luck, and I cannot use absolute positioning as i rely on the div(1) to position other div's.

A brief example can be found here - _

Trying to get the _ speech bubble to overlay the Google map.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a code example would be a good idea, because there are a lot of details we need to know. (for example. what other divs rely on div(1)'s position?)

You cannot overlay divs in the box-model or inline(model).

You can try using negative margin to move the div(1) over div(2), but this is not the elegant solution.

You should reconsider using absolute positioning, as it's clearly the preferable solution.

Comment: Uploaded the file I'm having problems with, I've just brushed this together now so please ignore any small discrepancies http://itgeekgroup.com/ trying to get the itgeek speech bubble to overlay on top of the Google maps image.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing the div(1) with the background image below a semi-transparent Google maps container, because then you could still have access to the Google Maps Controls. This could be accomplished by using the `opacity` and `z-index` CSS properties on both containers.

**Here is a JS fiddle with a live demo using the Google Maps API: [jsfiddle.net/Xk87Y/](http://jsfiddle.net/Xk87Y/)**